# How to generate a link in an email that calls ajax

Tags: php, mysql, email

I need for my current project a link that provides 2x timestamp(MySQL) 1x integer and 2x char. I know how to send an email with PHP but I don't know how to put all types together in one link. After someone clicked it, it should direct you to another PHP site in which I want to call a procedure. I should be save to, therefore maybe hashing?

An example:

http://examplesite.com/teachers/accepted.php?begintime=...,endtime=...,id=...,rndchar=...,rndcharv2=...

I hope someone could help me :)

Comment: what do you mean by *"that calls ajax"* ?

Comment: and what does this have to do with mysql and hashing? Your question is unclear. In any case, someone provided you with an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$link = "<a href=\"http://examplesite.com/teachers/accepted.php?begintime=\"" . $begintimeVariable . "\"&endtime=\"" . $endtimeVariable . "\"&id=\"" . $idVariable . "\"randchar=\"" . $randcharVariable . "\"&rndcharv2=\"" . $rndcharv2Variable . "\">Link Text</a>";

mail($to, "subject", $link,$headers);
?>
```

Then on accepted.php you will get the query strings using `$_GET` then if they are all set and not empty, u do what u need to do

Comment: You realize that without full/proper headers that `mail($to, "subject", $link);` will most likely end up being marked as spam or rejected altogether. :You also made a typo `Link Text<a>` it should be `</a>`. Edit: which you fixed just now.

Comment: You are correct thought i wrote the `</a>`  hearders I edit that left them out since OP said they knw how to send email @Fred-ii-